# RQDA does not read Imported UTF-8 characters in UTF-8 encoded .txt

Tags: r, utf-8, rqda

Trying to import a database of texts for analysis with RQDA. The database consists of word to text converted files with UTF-8 encoding. RQDA is supposed to read UTF-8, however UTF-8 characters like (ą, č, ę, ė, į, š, ų, ū) are not recognized after import to RQDA.

I'm using the "write.FileList" function for import. Its details state, that

"The file content will be converted to UTF-8 character before being written to *.rqda. The original content can be in any suitable encoding, so you can inspect the content correctly; In other words, the better practices is to used the corresponding encoding (you can get a hint by localeToCharset function) to save the imported files."

```r
write.FileList(FileList, encoding = .rqda$encoding, con = .rqda$qdacon)

addFilesFromDir("C:\\output", pattern = "*.txt$")
```

write.FileList imports the database of text to RQDA, but UTF-8 characters are not recognized.

Shows this warning:

"In rsqlite_fetch(res@ptr, n = n) :
Don't need to call dbFetch() for statements, only for queries"

Comment: When the encoding towards UTF-8 does not work, sometimes it works for me to code towards ANSI under the Windows OS.